# How do I customize the cells of a specific row in a dgrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'd like to make a grid that looks like this:
[Dgrid with custom header cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfnGq.png)

I achieved the above picture by defining a renderHeaderCell: function within my grid's column definition.

```
        // Customize header cells
        this._columns.slice(1).forEach(
            function(column){
                column.renderHeaderCell = function(headerCellNode) {

                    // Add class to header cell
                    headerCellNode.classList.add("simbio-datasheet-header");

                    // Create header labels
                    var headerLabelDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    var headerTextNode = document.createTextNode(
                            "label" in column ? column.label : column.field);
                    headerLabelDiv.appendChild(headerTextNode);

                    // Create header comboboxes
                    var comboBoxNode = put("div.combobox"),
                        us_states = ["CA", "MA", "OH", "FL"],
                        us_cities = ["Los Angeles", "Boston", "Columbus", "Miami"];
                    var combobox1 = new SimBiologyComboBox({values: us_states});
                    var combobox2 = new SimBiologyComboBox({values: us_cities});
                    combobox1.placeAt(comboBoxNode);
                    combobox2.placeAt(comboBoxNode);
                    combobox1.startup();
                    combobox2.startup();

                    // Append everything to headerCellNode
                    headerCellNode.appendChild(headerLabelDiv);
                    headerCellNode.appendChild(comboBoxNode);
                }
            });
```

In this context columns is defined as:

```
this._columns = [
            {
                field      : "Count",
                label      : "",
                width      : 25,
                resizable  : false
            },
            {
                field      : "A",
                label      : "A",
                width      : 75
            },
            {
                field      : "B",
                label      : "B",
                width      : 75,
                sortable   : false
            }]
```

BUT, I achieved this by modifying the headerCells

Is there a way I can modify the non-header cells (defaultCell) and get the same effect?

I'd not like to modify all the cells under a specific column to look like this. Only the cells of one row.

(I've tried mixing in the Editor mixin into my grid. But this approach modifies all the cells of a given column... I could not figure out how to modify the cells of a given row)

Comment: There is a `renderCell` function that is associated with each column. But whatever you will do in it will apply for all the rows. So, to modify just one row, it has to be done for all the columns and on the basis of some condition related to the data that will come in that particular cell.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu!

But, I don't know how to redefine renderCell() while adding data to the store (Observable(.. Memory(...))

I'm using a store-backed grid. I add row data items into the store and it calls the insertRow() method (of List.js) deep in the call stack. And renderCell() gets invoked after that...

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/gamejunkie/4288890. In your case `renderCell` goes in the `this._columns` definition for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [create a mixin](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/demos/dTuned/dTuned.js#L79) class (as all the dgrid features) and override renderRow or renderCell or you do pass a formatter function which can return markup all for all columns you like.

There is a [demo](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/demos/dTuned/dTuned.js#L83) in dgrid/dTuned which shows how to customize rendering.